# iPhone: trouble with wrong credentials

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am writing an iPhone App that uses a HTTPS/SOAP service which needs user credentials. After I change the password used for these credentials from a valid to an invalid one I still get a valid response from the service, as if the password was never changed. When I restart the app (with the invalid password) the app immediately receives the expected '401' message.

Any hints what I might left out to code?

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...

I accidentally created an NSURLCredential object with persistence NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone.
Silly me....